# Counting trees according to endpoints

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Question: Is there a nice (or any) formula for the generating function 
          $$T(x,y) = \sum_{m,n} t_{m,n} x^my^n,$$ 
where $t_{m,n}$ is the number of trees with $m$ vertices and $n$ endpoints?

Here only the case of unlabeled and unrooted trees is considered.

The hope is that $T(x,-1)$ will have visibly nonnegative coefficients,
 thereby proving (if true) that for a given number of vertices, there
 are never more trees with an odd number of endpoints than with an even
 number.  (The trivial case of a single vertex is excluded).

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that the coefficient of $x^my^n$ in $T(x,y)$ accounts for trees with $m$ vertices and $n$ endpoints.

Comment: yes - sorry it was unclear

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that. Also, I confirm your conjecture for $m\leq 50$ -- see http://oeis.org/A262395

Answer (score 4):

A table of counts, and mention of the generating function is on OEIS at [A055290](http://oeis.org/A055290).

Comment: Thanks very much for the reference.  Unfortunately, just plugging in y = -1 appears far from conclusive and so the nonnegativity above apparently remains open .